# Deixar marcar apenas um CheckBox table dinâmica

Tags: javascript, ajax

Eu tenho uma table, que eu crio ela dinamicamente, eu preciso que o usuário consiga marcar apenas uma `checkbox`, ou seja quando um tiver marcado, na hora que ele for marcar outro, ele desmarca o outro, e marca o novo.
Eu adiciono este campo na table, desta forma:

```
  + "<td>" + "<input type='checkbox' class='link-check' />" + "</td>"
```

Comment: Já tentou warpar a tabela num formulário e usar um radio button ao invés de um checkbox?

Comment: Não tentei, como posso fazer?

Comment: Coloque a tabela dentro de uma tag de form, como um formulário qualquer, e utilize radio buttons ao invés de checkbox. Ele faz exatamente isso, quando você marca um, o outro desmarca.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

se tiver dúvida de como implementar, mas é extremamente simples.
edit: na verdade, pelo que estou vendo aqui, você nem precisa colocar num formulário, só colocar o mesmo "name" em todos os radio buttons que eles ficam linkados, assim, ao marcar um o outro desmarca.

Comment: Foi solicitado por checkbox, por questão de estética, caso não seja possível a função, vou tentar desta forma.

Comment: É possível, só dá mais trabalho. Vou ver aqui e já te respondo, se ninguém responder antes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362284/uncheck-a-checkbox-if-another-checked-with-javascript

Se precisar que eu traduza avise.

Comment: Você pode utilizar *radio buttons* como já sugerido, pense na funcionalidade. A questão estética você pode alterar com CSS para fazer o *radio* parecer uma *checkbox*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traduzindo a resposta [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362284/uncheck-a-checkbox-if-another-checked-with-javascript)(adaptado):

```
+ "<td>" + "<input type='checkbox' class='link-check' onchange="cbChange(this)" />" + "</td>"

// ...

function cbChange(obj) {
  var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("link-check");
  for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
     if(cbs[i] !== obj) cbs[i].checked = false;
   }
}
```

Basicamente, o que foi feito foi o seguinte: A função pega todos os checkboxes com a classe 'link-check', e coloca na array cbs. Itera sobre todos eles, desmarcando todos, e então, marca apenas aquele que foi clicado. Então adicione essa função em um evento onchange em todos os checkboxes para que funcione em todos eles.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Ele está me retornando a seguinte mensagem, cbs.forEach is not a function.

Comment: Você chegou a verificar se o document.getElementsByClassName está capturando os checkboxes? Tente dar um console.log(cbs) para ver o conteúdo. forEach só irá funcionar caso a variável seja uma array. Se preferir pode fazer um laço comum ao invés do forEach, fiz desta forma por ser mais legível.

Comment: Eu dei um`console.log(cbs)` e retornou: `HTMLCollection [input.link-check]`

Comment: E ao utilizar o forEach ele retornou aquele erro? Vou editar com um for normal pra você tentar de novo, um seg.

Comment: Deu certo, mas dessa forma eu n consigo desmarcar o checkbox ?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, você queria algo como um radio button em forma de checkbox, não? Você quer ter a possibilidade de desmarcar todos também?

Comment: Queria ter a opção de que se o checkbox está marcado, ai ele clicar em cima de novo, ele desmarque também.

Comment: editei novamente, veja se ajuda.

Comment: Testei aqui e não funciona, vou ver aqui e já te retorno.

Comment: to testando também, vamos ver, obrigado.

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar, editei lá.

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado pela ajuda, agora funcionou certinho.